# What else can be collected, including onchain for the new solan token?

Tags: solana-program, token

What else can be collected, including onchain for the new solan token?

1. Ability to manage the smart contract of the token
2. Size of liquidity
3. sending large portions of the token to third party addresses
4. Creator (address) scammer
5. Ability to burn tokens
6. Ability to create tokens of new additional issue
7. ???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.